# Mongo query to find field within array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection called `collectionA` that contains an array of type objects.

Example:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("123456"),
"tags" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Bob D",
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "another name",
    }
    ...
```

How would I write a query that matches the name within the array of objects?
I've tried `db.getCollection('collectionA').find({ "name": "Bob D})` but that didn't work.

Comment: Could you add sample document from your collection and expected output  ?

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('collectionA').find({ "tags.name": "Bob D" })` since `name` is nested inside `tags`

Comment: @mickl I've tried your command except I'm getting back the entire object (objectId(123456)) instead of the individual objects within the tags array that name matches to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter nested array you can either use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) (as projection):

```
db.col.find({ "tags.name": "Bob D" }, { tags: { $elemMatch: { name: "Bob D" } } })
```

which returns **first** matching array element, or use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get multiple matching elements of `tags` array:

```
db.col.aggregate([ { $addFields: { tags: { $filter: { input: "$tags", as: "tag", cond: { $eq: [ "$$tag.name", "Bob D" ] } } } } } ])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both methods work.

Comment: Actually, to build off that, why do you need tags: { $elemMatch: { name: "Bob D" } in addition to db.col.find({ "tags.name": "Bob D" }? I know if I don't include elemMath, I get back the entire document instead of just the objects that matches with name.

Comment: Second argument of `find()` represents a projection which allows you to reshape the document you store in your db